# Static Routes between Multiple Subnets - ROUTER (WAN) + WiFi Mesh ROUTER

Tags: networking, netctl

I've got a standard router (192.168.1.1) that is connected to the internet. It also has the following connected to it:

- an un-managed switch which all wired devices connect to.
- a Tenda Mesh WiFi Router (192.168.1.9 >> 192.168.5.1) connected to it.

Devices connected to the Tenda have IPs of 192.168.5.x and I can't connect to them from devices connected to the main router.

UPDATE: I've seen some posts referencing 'Routes' within netctl, but I get:

```
Jan 14 22:56:00 deviceX network[3728]: Could not add route '192.168.5.0/24 via 192.168.1.9,' to interface 'eno1'
Jan 14 22:56:00 deviceX dhclient[3788]: receive_packet failed on eno1: Network is down
Jan 14 22:56:00 deviceX network[3728]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'mynet-eno1-dhcp'
```

My current netctl profile is:

```
Description='A basic dhcp ethernet connection'
Interface=eno1
Connection=ethernet
IP=dhcp
#Routes=('192.168.5.0/24 via 192.168.1.9', '192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1')
DHCPClient=dhclient
#DHCPReleaseOnStop=no
## for DHCPv6
IP6=dhcp
DHCP6Client=dhclient
## for IPv6 autoconfiguration
#IP6=stateless
```

In order to connect seamlessly between these two networks, how (and where) can I create a Static Route. Also, do I need to do this on multiple machines.  My computers are all running Arch Linux, including several Raspberry Pis which are always on, that could server as intermediate points, if that would work.

Comment: You do not add "secondary" gateways, you add static routes.

Comment: Either distribute static routes by DHCP to all hosts in the two segments, or, assuming the two routers are the default routing gateways in each segment, add a static route to each router. The latter will be less efficient. Alternatively: Don't let the Tenda Router use a different segment with its own DHCP, bridge it instead.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks, I didn't think there was any settings in the Tenda app, but I've dug a little deeper and changed them from DHCP to Bridge.  Many thanks.  Please do add your comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either distribute static routes by DHCP to all hosts in the two segments, or, assuming the two routers are the default routing gateways in each segment, add a static route to each router. The latter will be less efficient.

Alternatively: Don't let the Tenda Router use a different segment with its own DHCP, bridge it instead.

Comment: The simplest answer is often the easiest. I changed the settings, which were buried in settings, to BRIDGE mode, away from DHCP.  Thank you.